# "Заявление" — с прописной или строчной?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

С какой буквы пишется слово "заявление": с прописной или строчной?

Comment: Заглавная, или прописная, — это большая буква. Строчная — это маленькая буква.

Comment: Текст приведите или контекст, в котором хотите видеть это слово.

Answer (score 3):

Если речь идёт об оформлении заявления, то в настоящее время это слово рекомендуется писать как заголовок, то есть с **прописной** буквы и без точки.

[**Как писать заявление?**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/104-rubric-69)

> Допускается, но считается устаревающим такой способ оформления (с точкой в конце, слово «заявление» со строчной буквы). [приводится пример]
>
> При таком оформлении «шапка» заявления представляет собой синтаксическое единство – предложение: такому-то (от) такого-то заявление (и точка в конце предложения, соответственно, нужна).
>
> Предлог «от» в шапке заявления можно пропустить.

**Итак, допустимы варианты:**

• тому-то от такого-то... Заявление

• тому-то от такого-то... ЗАЯВЛЕНИЕ

• тому-то от такого-то... заявление.

• тому-то такого-то... Заявление

• тому-то такого-то... ЗАЯВЛЕНИЕ

• тому-то такого-то... заявление.

Answer (score 0):

С заглавной (она же прописная) пишутся слова, если это имя собственное или начало предложения или заголовок. 
В остальных случаях используется **строчная** буква.